# Frustum volume solid of revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

Solve using integration and solids of revolution

The metal cover for a piece of machinery is 0.90 m in length, the radius of one end is 20 cm and the radius of the other end is 30cms as shown in the following diagram:
[image]

I have calculated the volume for the cylinder section but am having trouble with frustum section

Comment: Your frustrum is a cone with its top removed. Do you know the formula for the volume of a cone?

Comment: yes, i have it as V=1/3 pi h (R^2+Rr+r^2)

Comment: I should have said I have calculated the volume with the formula but I need to confirm it using integration and solids of revolution.

Comment: Two points on your frustrum are (-45,20) and (0,30). Find the line through these points and apply your solid of revolution formula between -45 and 0 as integral limits.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the truncated cone as being generated by the revolution of a straight line that goes through points $(-45,20)$ and $(0,30)$, i.e., $y=30-\frac{10}{9}x$.